# Why do I have problems trying to get Slic3r to load a config file?

Tags: slicing, slic3r, octoprint

I decided to fire up my 3D Printer again after a while.  I have new PCs, so I had to download [Slic3r](http://slic3r.org/) fresh, so I got the latest version (1.2.9).  Then I went and found my old config file.  It's really old, from 2013!

And Slic3r did not load it when I told it to, and consequently, when Octoprint was telling my Printrbot LC (custom) to print my things off [Thingiverse](http://octoprint.org/), it was not in the bed, and the x axis skipped a few nubs, as would happen when you tell it it's too far away.

I recall having to double and triple check Slic3r to make sure that it actually loaded the configuration I spent time crafting and honing.  However, it's obviously been 3-4 years since I last played with this stuff, and this is a very low level feature that should have been fixed at Day 0 or 1.

I presume that I'm doing something wrong.  Do I need to stand on 1 leg and hold my mouth just right?  I don't even know how I could screw it up...

**Update**

I changed from "Simple" mode to "Advanced" mode, and the config imported fine.  Though, I don't think it was my most recent config.  C'est la software!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed from "Simple" mode to "Advanced" mode, and the config imported fine. Though, I don't think it was my most recent config. C'est la software!

Also, I switched to Cura after this.